# Convex function defined in convex compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

Given a convex function $f : A \to \Bbb{R}$, where $A$ is a convex compact set from $\Bbb{R}^n$. How to prove that we can extend our function $F : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$, such that it stays convex.

We think that the solution is F(x) = sup{λf(y) + (1 − λ)f(z): x = λy + (1 − λ)z, y, z ∈ Ω,  λ >= 1}, it is clear that F(x) extends f(x), because of convexity of f,but can not prove that F(x) is convex.

Comment: In general, unless you allow extended values, you cannot. Take $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}$ defined on $-[1,1]$.

Comment: @copper.hat You probably want $-\sqrt {1-x^2}.$

Comment: @zhw.: Thanks. I meant to have $1-...$ but somehow forgot... I was thinking of a circle of radius one at $(0,1)$. So, I intended $x \mapsto 1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.